# How to handle multiple imports that have the same namespace?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, importerror

I'm working on a C++ command line application that is a Component Object Model (COM) client.  There are two COM server implementations and I'd like to support both of them in my program (choosable via a application parameter).

Both server are using the same namespace OmniRig, so everything clashes. I tried to split them into separate classes to avoid the conflict but that didn't work.  Is is possible to support both COM servers and how would I go about doing so?

OmniRigV1.h:

```
#include "OmniRigBase.h"

#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Afreet\OmniRig\OmniRig.exe"
using namespace OmniRig;

class OmniRigV1 : public OmniRigBase {...}
```

OmniRigV2.h:

```
#include "OmniRigBase.h"

#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Omni-Rig V2\omnirig2.exe"
using namespace OmniRig;

class OmniRigV2 : public OmniRigBase {...}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ProgramOptions options(argc, argv);
    OmniRigBase* omnirig;
    switch (options.getOmnirigVersion()) {
        case OmniRigVersion::OmniRigVersion1:
            omnirig = new OmniRigV1(options);
            break;
        case OmniRigVersion::OmniRigVersion2:
            omnirig = new OmniRigV2(options);
            break;
        default:
            exit(E_OPTION_OMNIRIG_VERSION);
    }
...
```

Complete code at:
https://github.com/cniesen/IcomClockOmniRig/tree/adf7ce1b0ef716ec2f72d50bffbada4e811a52cf/src

Comment: `#import` directive has `rename_namespace` option.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, that did the trick.  Thank you very much.  Do you want to add the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ingor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) mentioned in the comments, I needed to use the `rename_namespace` option with the `#import` directive:

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Afreet\OmniRig\OmniRig.exe" rename_namespace("OmniRig1")
```

and

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Omni-Rig V2\omnirig2.exe" rename_namespace("OmniRig2")
```

Now each implementation can be accessed with the appropriate name like `OmniRig1::OmniRigX` and `OmniRig2::OmniRigX`

Credit and thanks goes to Ingor.